# Check whether SOCKS5 proxy server support UDP

Tags: proxy, udp, tunneling, socks, socks5-proxy

Suppose I have UDP server that listen incoming message on `192.168.43.1:1234` and SOCKS5 proxy server that listen on `192.168.43.2:9999`.

How do I check whether SOCKS5 proxy server support UDP when accessed with a SOCKS5 client?

I know that SOCKS5 support UDP, but I just want make sure if it's really supported. I expect UDP server receive message from client and client got reply from server with `netcat` or similiar tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by testing in the following way:

- You will need to ask your socks client to send an udp packet to 192.168.43.1:1234 via the socks proxy server, and on 192.168.43.1:1234
- You will need to have previously started a program that listens to
  UDP packets.

An example using Dante's `socksify` wrapper, and the OpenBSD version of `nc` (netcat) is given below:

1. On host 192.168.43.1, start `nc` as this:

   ```shell
   nc -lu 192.168.43.1 1234
   ```
2. On another host, run `nc` via Dante's `socksify` wrapper like this:

   ```shell
   echo hello | SOCKS_SERVER=127.0.0.1:1080 socksify nc -u 192.168.43.1 1234
   ```

In 2. we assume that the socks server you want to use is running on address 127.0.0.1:1080, so you will of course need to change that to what is the correct socks server address in your case.

You can then verify that the `netcat` started in 1. received the string `hello`, and you should also verify that the socks server log shows the UDP packet was passed via it.  In case the socks server is a Dante server, the log would contain something like this:

```
sockd[1124749]: info: pass(1): udp/udpassociate -: 127.0.0.1.33817 127.0.0.1.48887 -> 192.168.50.151.50434 192.168.43.1.1234 (5)
```

Links:

- [Dante's `socksify`](https://www.inet.no/dante/doc/1.4.x/socksify.1.html)
- [OpenBSD's `netcat`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/netcat-openbsd/nc.1.en.html)

Other `netcat` variants will work too, but they have wildly different option syntaxes. The above is an example using the variant that is in OpenBSD.

Answer (score 0):

To your pleasure :

https://github.com/ezbik/scripts/tree/master/udpchk

1. test by IP
2. test by Hostname
3. test of DNSleak